# Delphi Memory Leak or Access Violation while using objects and interfaces

Tags: delphi, memory-management, interface

Currently I'm stuck a little bit regarding objects and interfaces and their memory management. I have a class which inherits from `TInterfacedPersistent`, called `TAbstractBaseDTO`. I also have an interface `IDuplicatable` with a function `function CreateDuplicate: TAbstractBaseDTO`.

I am using interfaces to achieve abstraction, not to manage memory and that is why I am using `TInterfacedPersistent` as an ancestor class.

Unit.pas

```pascal
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, System.Actions, Vcl.ActnList,
  Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TAbstractBaseDTO = class abstract (TInterfacedPersistent)
    public
      constructor CreateEmpty; virtual; abstract;
  end;

  IDuplicatable = interface
    ['{153275DC-71C0-4CB6-B933-667419950C68}']
    function CreateDuplicate: TAbstractBaseDTO;
  end;

  TCountryMasterDataDTO = class (TAbstractBaseDTO, IDuplicatable)
    public
      constructor CreateEmpty; override;
      function CreateDuplicate: TAbstractBaseDTO;
  end;

  TBaseDataForm = class(TForm)
    ActionList1: TActionList;
    actDuplicate: TAction;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure actDuplicateExecute(Sender: TObject);
    strict private
      var
        FDataObject: TAbstractBaseDTO;
      function FetchBusinessObject: TAbstractBaseDTO;
    public
      procedure LoadData(ADataObject: TAbstractBaseDTO);
      destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

var
  BaseDataForm: TBaseDataForm;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TBaseDataForm.LoadData(ADataObject: TAbstractBaseDTO);
begin
  FDataObject.Free;
  FDataObject := ADataObject;
end;

destructor TBaseDataForm.Destroy;
begin
  FDataObject.Free;
  inherited;
end;

constructor TCountryMasterDataDTO.CreateEmpty;
begin
  Create;
end;

function TCountryMasterDataDTO.CreateDuplicate: TAbstractBaseDTO;
begin
  Result := TCountryMasterDataDTO.Create;
end;

procedure TBaseDataForm.actDuplicateExecute(Sender: TObject);
var
  LAbstractBaseDTO: IDuplicatable;
  LAbstractBaseDTODuplicate: TAbstractBaseDTO;
begin
  LAbstractBaseDTO := Self.FetchBusinessObject as IDuplicatable;
  try
    LAbstractBaseDTODuplicate := LAbstractBaseDTO.CreateDuplicate;
    Self.LoadData(LAbstractBaseDTODuplicate);
  finally
    LAbstractBaseDTO := nil;
  end;
end;

function TBaseDataForm.FetchBusinessObject: TAbstractBaseDTO;
begin
  Result := TCountryMasterDataDTO.Create;
end;

end.
```

When I run `actDuplicate` action FastMM4 reports a memory leak on shutdown.

However, changing the execute function to:

```pascal
procedure TBaseDataForm.actDuplicateExecute(Sender: TObject);
var
  LAbstractBaseDTO: TAbstractBaseDTO;
  LAbstractBaseDTODuplicate: TAbstractBaseDTO;
begin
  LAbstractBaseDTO := Self.FetchBusinessObject;
  try
    LAbstractBaseDTODuplicate := (LAbstractBaseDTO as IDuplicatable).CreateDuplicate;
    Self.LoadData(LAbstractBaseDTODuplicate);
  finally
    LAbstractBaseDTO.Free;
  end;
end;
```

will immediately raise an access violation, when running the action.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Does `FetchBusinessObject` create a new object that must be freed? Why is `CreateDuplicate` returning an object reference instead of an interface? How does `LAbstractBaseDTODuplicate` get used after it is created? Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Yes, the result from `FetchBusinessObject` has to be freed somewhere. Actually the `LAbstractBaseDTODuplicate` wil be loaded in a form to populate a `FDMemTable`. Also this form will free the current object and replace it by the `LAbstractBaseDTODuplicate`. I'll try to add only the relevant code, as all of this happens in multiple forms. I have also changed the interface method to return a `IDuplicatable` instead of `TAbstractBaseDTO`

Comment: The only good reason to ever derive from `TInterfacedPersistent` is to enable `interface` reference counting. Which means any object you create that derives from `TInterfacedPersistent` should be used only via `interface` references, not `object` references. If you need object references, don't use `TInterfacedPersistent`, use `TPersistent` instead, and manually `Free` the objects when needed.

Comment: For that matter, I wonder why you are using `T(Interfaced)Persistent` at all?  Those base classes are meant for enabling RTTI on classes, such as for DFM streaming, which the code shown is not utilizing (ie, no `published` properties).

Comment: Ok thanks! I actually saw the use of an interface more like a container with a specific behaviour ('can be duplicated'), than actually let delphi do the memory management for me. I figured out, if I move the entire content from `actDuplicateExecute` to the specific form, and just call it from the baseform, it works. Not really sure, where it's going wrong with the casts. By creating a minimal reproducible example, the error unfortunately also did not occur. So probably I messe something up with the casts. Anyway, it works now and thanks David and Remy

Comment: Main issue here is that you are mixing interface references with object references. Your code is a bit messy so it is hard to say what exactly is going wrong there. You should create proper [mcve] if you want to get some more specific answers. `TInterfacedPersistent` class has reference counting disabled and you need to manually manage its memory. However, at the point where you Free such object you must ensure that there are no interfaces pointing to it because if there are, you will have AV when that reference goes out of scope and interface `_Release` method will be called on dead instance.

Comment: If you want to involve interfaces, then it would be simpler to leave memory management to interfaces and use `TInterfacedObject` as base class as designing class hierarchies around classes with reference counting disabled requires slightly more knowledge (due to more subtle issues you can have with casting and storing references) that using reference counted ones.

Comment: But, looking at your classes and the fact that you have base class, why use interface at all? Just add virtual function `CreateDuplicate` at base class and that is it. If some of descendant classes cannot be duplicated then you can either return nil from `CreateDuplicate` as indication that object cannot be duplicated or add another virtual function `IsDuplicatable: Boolean` that will tell you whether particular descendant class supports duplication or not.

Comment: Thanks Dalija! I was trying to achieve this exact behaviour (is duplicatable or not) by using the interface, to only implement the function where the interface is implemented and to let the `Support` function handle all of the checking for me :). Like I said before, it's ok for me to do the memory management on my own (freeing the objects). That's not the reason i wanted to use the interface here. It's more like describing what my classes can do

Comment: I understand that you wanted to use interfaces as abstraction tool. However, their memory management is always more complicated than using simple classes without interfaces.

Comment: Again, if you want to get answers to your question you will need to reduce above code a bit and remove all unnecessary stuff. You don't need a complete object declaration with all fields. Also you posted two declarations of `IDuplicatable` interface one that returns `IDuplicatable` type and another that returns `TAbstractBaseDTO` type. Which one is it in your real code? That can drastically change what is happening in your code.

Comment: Also, you have too much unnecessary typecasting. from your code it seems like you want to return `TAbstractBaseDTO` from `CreateDuplicate` not `IDuplicatable` as once you have duplicate you want to use that instance for doing other things, not calling `CreateDuplicate` again, so it makes no sense to return `IDuplicatable`.  Next, why do you need to create duplicate at all? Since you are freeing `LAbstractBaseDTO` which is returned by `FetchBusinessObject`, why don't you pass that object to `LoadData` directly?

Comment: Thanks again @DalijaPrasnikar. Originally I just want to return a `TAbstractBaseDTO` from `CreateDuplicate`. Sorry for not pointing out, the `CreateDuplicate` method does not return an exact copy of the object, but will copy some values and reset others. But important to note maybe, it's a new object, which has to  be freed. Therefore I want that logic in the class as kind of business logic, and load this  new object in the `LoadData` method, not just the old one. You're right, that I don't need the result as `IDuplicatable`, so I have changed it back to return type `TAbstractBaseDTO`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are experiencing is because there is alive interface reference to the object you have already destroyed.

In this case it is hidden implicit interface reference created by compiler when you typecasted `LAbstractBaseDTO` as `IDuplicatable`.

```
LAbstractBaseDTODuplicate := (LAbstractBaseDTO as IDuplicatable).CreateDuplicate;
```

This hidden interface reference will be cleared by compiler in the method epilogue and this will call `_Release` method on the already destroyed object instance.

If you run your code with FASTMM in full debug mode, FASTMM will detect such scenario and show error message, followed by a stack trace:

FASTMM has detected an attempt to use an interface of a freed object. An access violation will now be raised in order to abort the current operation.

To solve that problem you need to conver that implicit interface reference to explicit one under your control and then you can clear that reference yoursel, before you free the object it references.

```
procedure TBaseDataForm.actDuplicateExecute(Sender: TObject);
var
  LAbstractBaseDTO: TAbstractBaseDTO;
  LAbstractBaseDTODuplicate: TAbstractBaseDTO;
  LDuplicatable: IDuplicatable;
begin
  LAbstractBaseDTO := FetchBusinessObject;
  try
    // save interface reference to a variable
    LDuplicatable := LAbstractBaseDTO as IDuplicatable;
    LAbstractBaseDTODuplicate := LDuplicatable.CreateDuplicate;
    LoadData(LAbstractBaseDTODuplicate);
  finally
    LDuplicatable := nil;
    LAbstractBaseDTO.Free;
  end;
end;
```